# WADPerformanceCountersTable is not created

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to collect some performance counters from a worker role and WADPerformanceCountersTable is never created.

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

    DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

    var procTimeConfig = new PerformanceCounterConfiguration();
    procTimeConfig.CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time";
    procTimeConfig.SampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    diagConfig.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(procTimeConfig);
    diagConfig.PerformanceCounters.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagConfig);

    return base.OnStart();
}
```

I have tried different log tables like WADLogsTable and WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable and both are created correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, this problem is caused by the language of the system. It is explained here:

[Error in Azure Emulator when creating Performance Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857918/error-in-azure-emulator-when-creating-performance-counters)

My Windows is the Spanish version, so the name of the performance counters must be in Spanish:

```
procTimeConfig.CounterSpecifier = @"\Procesador(_Total)\% de tiempo de procesador";
```

Be careful, this only works locally, not on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in my application.  Since your ScheduledTransferPeriod is 1 minute are you letting your role run for at least 1 minute?  That's when the table will be created.

Comment: Yes, I have waited for more than a minute. I am starting to think that this is a bug caused by the regional settings, my system is not in English.