# Errors appearing in Azure Compute Emulator

Tags: azure

I have developed a simple Cloud Service with one simple WebRole, for testing purposed.
I am using the latest Azure SDK, with Visual Studio 2012.

Everything works as I needed it to,
But when I take a look at the `Compute Emulator UI` I can see error messages that keep re-appearing every few seconds.

I really have not done anything special, so I can't think of any code snip to post here...

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Here is the error message dump:

```
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-05-24T14:28:01.536Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7808
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1512
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     062191bb-aee7-4075-bdb1-79521fb
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-05-24T14:28:01.536Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7808
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1512
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     062191bb-aee7-4075-bdb1-79521fb
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

Apparently, I had my `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg` file configured with `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString` element pointing to the Cloud storage instead of my local development storage.

Changing the element value back to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` solved the issue, and I can now see the logs from my WebRole using the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the Diagnostics Plugin and maybe is related to this question, asked before: [Error in Azure Emulator when creating Performance Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857918/error-in-azure-emulator-when-creating-performance-counters)

Just in case you do not need Diagnostics in your Development-Enviroment, you can ignore it or remove the Plugin from your ServiceDefinition.csdef

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, the other question doesn't seems to be fully related, and I do need Diagnostics in my development environment... any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you know which part of your diagnostics.wadcfg configuration file casuses this error? Or is it the plugin in general that causes the problem?